# Pure CSS Style element if it wrapped or not (without Javascript)

Tags: css

In the following clip, if the `#TWO` wraps, I wish to not show the black left border of `#TWO`. The black border is to separate the items visually when they are aside only. When wrapped having the border between them vertically is okay too.

Currently I do this with JavaScript (e.g. `if (TWO.offsetLeft > 50) ...`), but hope it might be doable with purely CSS.

```css
#PARENT {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  padding: 16px;  
}

#ONE {
  background: #fee;
}

#TWO {
  background: #efe;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="PARENT">
  <div id="ONE" class="child">One sentenance that is long or maybe short</div>
  <div id="TWO" class="child">Two is also unknown length</div>
</div>
```

Update: Made it more apparent that the width is determined by the content, not some fixed static value.

Comment: use the gap property and add background to the container

Comment: @TemaniAfif That would work only if the children are growing, or else you will get a black block on the right when children wrap?

Comment: @AmauryHanser one can just use `flex-grow`, see the answer I made with @TemaniAfif suggestion

Comment: @run_the_race, sure, it depends on the specific use case, maybe you don't want your item to grow, who knows? :)

Comment: @AmauryHanser, no problem, if you don't want your item to grow, place the item you don't want to grow in a child of the element that does grow, making it appear like it does not grow, but the border gap will still appear correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use media queries?

```css
/* adding to neutralize default browser styles */
body { 
  margin: 0;
}
/* adding to make math easier */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#PARENT {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  min-width: 200px;
  padding: 16px;  
}

#ONE {
  background: #fee;
}

#TWO {
  background: #efe;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 400px) { 
    #TWO {
      border-left: 2px solid black;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="PARENT">
  <div id="ONE" class="child">one</div>
  <div id="TWO" class="child">two</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I made it more clear its not just a simple media query because the width is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

Using @TemaniAfif's comment:

> Use the gap property and add background to the container

PS: If you post a solution I will delete this answer:

```css
#PARENT {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: black;
  gap: 2px;
}

.child {
  padding: 16px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#ONE {
  background: #fee;
}

#TWO {
  background: #efe;
}
```

```html
<div id="PARENT">
  <div id="ONE" class="child">One sentenance that is long or maybe short</div>
  <div id="TWO" class="child">Two is also unknown length</div>
</div>
```